# Pipe video and audio to ffmpeg from OpenRTSP

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to record rtsp stream in HLS format using openRTSP and ffmpeg. openRTSP receives rtsp and pipe to ffmpeg to record,

Here is the command I used and which works fine

```
openRTSP -D 10 -v -t -c -b 800000 rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov | .././ffmpeg -r 15 -i - -codec copy -hls_list_size 65535 -hls_time 2 "./live.m3u8"
```

Note in above commnad -v is for video only.

But now I need to record audio also so I removed -v option, but the video is not getting recorded. It's just creating two files named
`audio-MPEG4-GENERIC-1` and `video-H264-2` no HLS video file. I think some problem with piping. Can anyone help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

use -4 switch this will output mp4 file to the stdout this can be picked up from the ffmpeg via -i -- if I remember correctly